# Populate jqGrid selectlist in edit form from MVC controller

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am returning a string jqGrid from controller, but dropdown does not populate.

Grid code on View:

```
        {
            name: 'FundCode', index: 'FundCode', editable: true, edittype: "select",
            editoptions: {
                dataUrl: '@Url.Action("PopulateDdl", "FundCode")'
            },
            buildSelect: function (response) {
                var data = typeof response === "string" ? $.parseJSON(response.responseText) : response, s = "<select>";

                s += '<option value="0">--Select Fund--</option>';

                $.each(data, function() {
                    s += '<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>';

                })
            }
        }
```

Controller method returning the string:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult PopulateDdl()
    {
        var fundCodes = repo.GetFundCodes();

        var codeList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var t in fundCodes)
        {
            codeList.Add(t.FundCode.ToString());
        }

        return Json(codeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This returns a list to the grid but I get an error, "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ["1", "2", "3", etc ]

I have also tried returning as MVC SelectListItem to same result.

UPDATE - I added the closing select.  It did not fix the issue.  I then noticed the 'buildSelect' was not in the same group as the dataUrl.  I moved it and the error changed. Now the error is "Unexpected token u" it says it is on the line 1.

New view code:

```
        {
            name: 'FundCode', index: 'FundCode', editable: true, edittype: "select",
            editoptions: {
                dataUrl: '@Url.Action("PopulateDdl", "FundCode")',
                buildSelect: function (response) {
                    var data = typeof response === "string" ? $.parseJSON(response.responseText) : response, s = "<select>";
                    s += '<option value="0">--Select Fund--</option>';
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        s += '<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>';
                    })
                    s += "</select>";
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be with `s = "<select>"`, you are opening the tag but never closing it, this could be ruining your html , try if closing the select can solve the issue :

```
{
            name: 'FundCode', index: 'FundCode', editable: true, edittype: "select",
            editoptions: {
                dataUrl: '@Url.Action("PopulateDdl", "FundCode")'
            },
            buildSelect: function (response) {
                var data = typeof response === "string" ? $.parseJSON(response.responseText) : response, s = "<select>";

                s += '<option value="0">--Select Fund--</option>';

                $.each(data, function() {
                    s += '<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>';

                })

                s += '</select>'; // <<<<<<< close the select
            }
        }
```

**Edit**

That error is normally seen when the value given to JSON.parse is actually undefined. So, I would check the code that is trying to parse this - most likely you are not parsing the actual string correctly:

- Make sure that there is valid data in response.responseText
- Make sure that the data is not in actually in `response` variable, if so you shouldn't then be
  using response.responseText in the first place
- Make sure that data has not already been in a json format and you are parsing it again which most probably might be the case since you are returning the array after using `Json` function in JAVA.
- After building the select, you shall use return `s` in order for it to take effect

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial that shows how to do the server side stuff, ie prepare the list so it gets to the client as well defined json?

Comment: Currently the string getting to the client looks like this:  ["8:Dallas;","10:Denver;","34:Michigan;", .... ]

Comment: @BattlFrog I guess some examples as [tutorial1](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/), [tutorial2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm), [tutorial3](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/), will help you, and if there is something that is not clear, feel free to ask I will be glad to help :)